# Regex for avoiding basic math operators

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex(java) for below condition:-
String will start with $ and it must not include the basic math operators " + -".If these comes, it should return "false". i used

```
(\\S).*[^+\\-]
```

for the same

And my test cases are:

```
$india
$india+
$india+my
```

This was okay for first two conditions, either resulting first into true and second into false(since + is there) .But it was failing for the third case. Instead of showing false, it keeps showing true.

Comment: `\$[^+-]+` seems to be what you want. https://regex101.com/r/EgctE3/1

Comment: i tried this, but again not working for the third condition

Comment: You can see in the regex101 link in my comment that it is not matching the third string which is what you have stated should be the case. Please post the exact code you are using.

Comment: @jrook your demo has anchors which aren't in your comment, that's why it doesn't work in OPs code

Comment: Updated the demo: https://regex101.com/r/EgctE3/2 . Does this satisfy all your test cases?

Comment: @jrook sorry I meant your demo was correct but the regex you posted in your comment wasn't as it was missing the anchors necessary to make it work properly

Comment: yes,it is working
Thanks a lot @jrook

Answer (score 0):

> ^\$[^+-]+$

this works for all three